# How to pass a Form component along with values to Modal in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am developing a component where I need to hold the certain form inputs(FN, LN, PhNo, EmailID) in the form. I created a separate component for this Form as (**ContactUS.js**) and I created a separate component for the Modal(**Modal.js**). On the button click I need to open the modal with the inputs from the **ContactUS** component, from there I need to submit the form. I have imported the contactUS inside the Modal Component and I passed that under Modal body. I have tried to pass the props but I am getting following errors:
**react-dom.development.js:2942 Uncaught Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML**. I looked various solution but I coudln't understand the issue properly, anybody can guide me what I am doing wrong ? Thanks in advance. I have wrote down the both component below.

```
  **MODAL COMP:**
    function ModalComp() {
      //Modal state
      const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    
      //handlemodal logic
      const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
      const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    
      const onLoginFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        handleClose();
      };
    
      return (
        <div style={bgDivStyle}>
          <div className="content">
            <Button variant="info" className="button" onClick={handleShow}>
              Contact US
            </Button>
            <Modal show={show}>
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Contact Form</Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>
                <ContactUs onSubmit={onLoginFormSubmit} />
              </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }




 **ContactUS Comp:**
    function ContactUs({ onSubmit }) {
      //Form fields
      const [data, setData] = useState({
        FirstName: "",
        LastName: "",
        emailID: "",
        phoneNo: "",
        company: "",
        website: "",
        ExpainProj: "",
      });
    
      const {
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        emailID,
        phoneNo,
        company,
        website,
        ExpainProj,
      } = data;
    
      //inputhandler function
      const inputHandler = (e) => {
        setData({ ...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      };
      return (
        <div className="main">
          <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your First Name"
                value={FirstName}
                onChange={inputHandler}
                name="FirstName"
              >
                First Name
              </Form.Control>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your Last Name"
                value={LastName}
                onChange={inputHandler}
                name="LastName"
              >
                Last Name
              </Form.Control>
              <Form.Control
                type="number"
                placeholder="Enter your Ph Number"
                value={phoneNo}
                onChange={inputHandler}
                name="phoneNo"
              >
                Phone Number
              </Form.Control>
              <Form.Control
                type="email"
                placeholder="Enter your EmaiID"
                value={emailID}
                onChange={inputHandler}
                name="emailID"
              >
                Enter EMailID
              </Form.Control>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your Company Name"
                value={company}
                onChange={inputHandler}
                name="company"
              >
                Company Name
              </Form.Control>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your Company Website"
                value={website}
                onChange={inputHandler}
                name="website"
              >
                Company Website
              </Form.Control>
              <Form.Control
                type="textarea"
                rows="3"
                placeholder="Describe about your project"
                value={ExpainProj}
                onChange={inputHandler}
                name="ExpainProj"
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it clearly. The input (Form.Control) should not have childrens. If you want to put label for the input you should use `<Form.Label>First name</Form.Label>`.

You can check some examples here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/form-control/